# How to hide certain factors when plotting with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this example I would like to not show the factors 6 and 8 from `carb` but I still want to use them to calculate the proportions.

```
ggplot(mtcars)+ aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(carb)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this with ggplot knowing that I have multiple factors that I want to hide?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this: `ggplot(subset(mtcars,!cyl%in%c(6,8)))+ aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(carb)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")`

Comment: Sorry I meant from factor `carb`. However with your solution, factors 6 and 8 will not be used to calculate the proportions

Comment: Maybe calculate the proportions beforehand and use geom_col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about calculating the proportions before you create the plot?

```
mtcars %>%
    dplyr::count(cyl,carb) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!carb %in% c(6,8)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=factor(cyl),y=pct,fill=factor(carb))) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, carb) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(p = n / sum(n)) %>%
  filter(!carb %in% c(6, 8)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y= p, fill = factor(carb))) +
    geom_col()
```